# Creating a new file on an SD card

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a program in android studio that writes on a .txt file on the sd card/creates a new one if there isn't one already, but it never creates the file and I'm constantly getting this exception:

java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Here is my code:

```
public void write(String filename) throws IOException {
    EditText contentTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fileTxtField);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Demo/"+filename;
    File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("File Created").setMessage("File successfully created!").show();
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

    out.println(contentTxt.getText().toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest? Do you also request it at runtime using `requestPermissions()`? Also, please use `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Demo/"+filename);`. And bear in mind that none of this will work on Android Q and higher. Either use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` and write your file there, or use the Storage Access Framework to allow the user to pick a content location to use.